# Crash on use of CoefficientList

Tags: bugs, polynomials, crash

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 11.0.0**

*Three-argument form of* `CoefficientList` *is documented since 10.3 only.*

---

The Kernel of my *Mathematica* 10.4 seems to crash on certain use of the `CoefficientList` command. The line

```
CoefficientList[x + y^2, {x, y}]
```

produces the matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

as it should. However, when I try to extract the $2\times 2$ upper left submatrix by evaluating the following command, I get an instant crash:

```
CoefficientList[x + y^2, {x, y}, {2, 2}]
```

The strange thing is that this only happens in some occasions. For instance,

```
CoefficientList[x^2 + y, {x, y}, {2, 2}]
```

works just fine. Is there anyway around this problem (which I assume to be a bug) that does not decrease the speed of the operation? I'm working with high degree polynomials in two variables from which I need to extract the $100\times 100$ coefficient matrix as fast as possible.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this crashes my version of *Mathematica*---v10.0---and the third argument to `CoefficientList` was introduced in v10.3! But it seems that this is an undocumented feature in v10.0, because your second one (that doesn't crash) works for me, too. Weird.

Comment: Might be able to use `CoefficientArrays` as a workaround.

Comment: We do not add the [tag:bugs] tag to a question until your observations have been confirmed by other users. Nevertheless, I can also confirm this crash on 10.3, so I'll let you off this time.

Comment: More interestingly, `CoefficientList[x^2 + y^3, {x, y}, {2, 2}] // MatrixForm` crashes half of the time. When you first run it, it gives `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}`. When you run it the second time, Mathematica crashes. `CoefficientList[x^2 + y^3, {x, y}, {2, 2}]`, without `MatrixForm` crashes always.

Comment: This happens occasionally. This could be reproduced by running the code fresh on a new notebook after closing Mathematica completely.

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed as of Mathematica 11.0.0.

```
CoefficientList[x + y^2, {x, y}, {2, 2}]

(* {{0, 0}, {1, 0}} *)
```